# Poles of analytic approximation of step function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, step-function

In complex analysis, I am using $$H(x)=e^{-e^{-Rx}}$$ as an analytic approximation of the step function(for large R).

This function seems to be entire since it only has exponents(I did not prove this). However, I noticed that it may have poles at negative infinity.

So my questions are:

1. Are there any poles/singularities?
2. If so, what are the residues?
3. R is also the radius of my circular contour centered at zero. R will approach infinity. Are the singularities included in the contour?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. $e^{-e^{-R x}}$ approximates $1_{x > 0}$ locally uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$. But it explodes for every $x \not \in \mathbb{R}$. Yes $f_R(z) e^{-e^{-R z}}$ is entire, being the composition of two entire functions, so it doesn't have any poles or singularities. As every non-constant entire function $f_R(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$.   $\int_{|z| = 1} f_R(1/z)  dz=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{|z|=1} \frac{(-1)^k e^{-kR/z}}{k!}dz= \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2i \pi \frac{(-1)^k (-Rk)}{k!}$

Comment: @reuns I don’t agree that the function explodes for every $x$. According to my analysis $H(a+bi)$ is of magnitude $exp(-e^{-aR}cos(Rb))$ which is between 0 and 1. (But this may be incorrect since this is equivalent to saying the function is bounded) Any idea?

Comment: @renus Well, now I have figured out my mistake and the function does blow up for certain ranges. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For $b \ne 0$, $\cos(Rb)$ will be negative infinitely often as $R \to \infty$

Comment: And I meant $f_R(z) = e^{-e^{-Rz}}$ is entire and as for any non-polynomial entire function, $f_R(1/z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$